# How Do I Pass A Method Reference to A Different Method in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, events, reference, methods

I would like to pass a reference of a method into another method and store it as a variable.  Later, I would like to use this reference to define an event handler.

When making an event handler, a method reference is passed like:

```
myButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(myButton_Click);
```

And if you look at the constructor for "RoutedEventHandler" from intelliSense, it looks like:

```
RoutedEventHandler(void(object, RoutedEventArgs))
```

What I would like to do is pass the method "myButton_Click" to a different static method and then create an event handler there. How do I pass the reference to the static method? I tried the following but it doesn't compile:

```
public class EventBuilder
{
    private static void(object, RoutedEventArgs) _buttonClickHandler;

    public static void EventBuilder(void(object, RoutedEventArgs) buttonClickHandler)
    {
        _buttonClickHandler = buttonClickHandler;
    }

    public static void EnableClickEvent()
    {
        myButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(_buttonClickHandler);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reference a Method Reference (called a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) in .NET), use the Handler name, rather than the signature.

```
public class EventBuilder
{
    private static RoutedEventHandler _buttonClickHandler;

    public EventBuilder(RoutedEventHandler buttonClickHandler)
    {
        _buttonClickHandler = buttonClickHandler;
    }

    public static void EnableClickEvent()
    {
        myButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(_buttonClickHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: if _buttonClickHandler is already a RoutedEventHandler, shouldn't I be able to just set it like myButton.Click += _buttonClickHandler?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Even in general usage, you can leave off the "new EventHandler(...)" syntax; i.e. myButton.Click += myButton_Click; is valid by itself.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
private static delegate void(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) _buttonClickHandler;
```